# Python Prime number wont return

Tags: python

I know this question has been answered before in various forms. However I am trying to get this to work the way I am writing it, so I can see what I am doing wrong when I tackle a programming question. Im trying to make a function that prints/returns all prime number in the range. However the program I wrote wont print anything. I tried make flow charts and commented everything. It makes sense to me but wont work. Any advice is appreciated!

```
def isPrime (n):                       ## we define a function
    primeList = [2, 3]                 ## 2 is the only even prime number
    i = 4
    while 3<i<n:                       # i is assigned to numbers 3 to n
        if i%2 == 1:                   # if odd do the following
            if i%3 != 0:               
                primeList.append(i)    # add  to prime list
            else:
                i%2 == False
        else:
            i = i + 1                 # since i%2 == 0 we restart loop
    return primeList
```

Comment: def isPrime (n):        ## we define a function
    primeList = [2, 3]  ## 2 is the only even prime number
    i = 4
    while 3<i<n: # i is assigned to numbers 3 to n
        if i%2 == 1:    # if odd do the following
            if i%3 != 0: # if i doesnt have a remainder equal to 0 it is prime
                primeList.append(i) # add  to prime list
            else:
                i%2 == False
        else:
            i = i + 1 # since i%2 == 0 we restart loop
    return primeList

Comment: It's unclear what algorithm you are implementing here. You seem to count a number as "prime" if it is divisible by neither 2 nor 3. What about the number 25? Also, the statement `i%2 == False` doesn't do anything (and it's not clear what you intend it to do). Finally, you fail to increment `i` in the case where it is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a rather essential `i += 1` if `i % 2 == 1`.

Try it this way:

```
def isPrime (n):                       ## we define a function
    primeList = [2, 3]                 ## 2 is the only even prime number
    i = 4
    while 3<i<n:                       # i is assigned to numbers 3 to n
        if i%2 == 1:                   # if odd do the following
            if i%3 != 0:               
                primeList.append(i)    # add  to prime list
            else:
                i%2 == False

        i = i + 1                 # since i%2 == 0 we restart loop
    return primeList
```

Also, keep in mind this function does not actually generate a list of prime numbers.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it helped me get the function to work. Now I realize why it doesnt generate a list of primes.

Answer (score 0):

Function should do only one thing, so I would make 2 functions:

- `def get_primes_in_range(start, stop):`
- `def is_prime(number):`

Function name should tell You exactly what it does. In Your code the function is named wrong. It's called `isPrime`, but it doesn't check if number is prime, it's returning the list of primes.

Our functions should look like this:

```
def get_primes_in_range(start, stop):
  list_of_primes = []
  for i in xrange(start, stop):
    if is_prime(i):
      list_of_primes.append(i)
  return list_of_primes

def is_prime(number):
  for index in range(1, number):
    if number % index == 0 and index != 1:
      return False
  return True
```

It's not super fast, but it do it's job.